# Sharing small images on whatsapp breaks the image

Tags: android, image, image-processing, whatsapp

I have an android app [Amazicons](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.taureano.amazicons) in android market. The problem is that it is an emoticon sharing app and i want that when the images from the app are shared on the whatsapp, they look like emoticons meaning the size should be small. Currently if i share an image from the app, the size is very big and does not seem like an emoticon.

If i try to scale the image down while sharing, using createScaledBitmap method, the image breaks really badly. Whatapp scales up the image again when it sends it so it breaks as i scaled it down earlier. Can someone help?

Comment: Hi Swati, Have you found a way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

> > Can someone help?

not really.
WhatsApp sends the image as a scaled up images to fit the screen. There's nothing your app can do to change WhatsApp (or any other app) behavior.

Comment: thanks for replying. I also thought the same thing that i cannot change the behaviour of other apps but i have seen some other apps sharing small images without break. Look at this for example. One of the screenshots shows a small size emoticons without break. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.plantpurple.emojidom

Comment: did you actually download and tested it? screenshots can be (and quite often are) easily photoshoped.

Comment: yes i did. I can see that the images being shared are centered in a white background. Maybe that can be the solution.

Comment: good catch. So there you go, the extra background makes the actual icon seems smaller.